# How can I use `scanf_s("%[^\n]s")` with a limit to the number of characters allowed? C

Tags: c, string, scanf

How can I use `scanf_s("%[^\n]s")` with a limit to the number of characters allowed? C
For example:
`scanf_s("%10s", ...);`
But how can i do this when theres `[^\n]` before the `%`?

Comment: The `s` in `"%[^\n]s"` is not part of the specifier `"%[^\n]"`. Do not code that in.  The example code you are using that uses it is a poor example of C.

Comment: Then what would you use to input a string?

Answer (score 1):

The `s` in format `"%[^\n]s"` serves no purpose.  Delete that `s`.

---

Likely OP wants something like:

```
char buf[100];
...
//           v---- Consume all leading white-space
if (scanf_s(" %[^\n]", buf, XXX sizeofbuf) == 1) {
//                     ^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  2 arguments
  Success(); 
} else {
  Fail(); 
}
```

where `XXX` is either `(int)` (Visual) or `(rsize_t)`/*nothing* per the C standard.

- `scanf_s()` is not portable to systems that do not implement `..._s` functions.
- `scanf_s()` may not read only one *line* as the `" "` reads white-space including multiple lines of only white-space.
- `scanf_s()` is a poor substitute to the preferable `fgets()` to read one *line* of user input.  Recommend to never use `scanf_s()` nor `scanf()` until you know why there are bad.

Alternative:

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  Success(); 
} else {
  Fail(); 
}
```

Comment: If characters are more than 100?

Comment: Why does "%[^\n]s" serves no purpose? It tells scanf to not stop reading when thers a white space and only stop when theres a newline. doesnt it?

Comment: @ZahidKhan With `char buf[100];`, the issue of not reading all the line begins not at _more than 100_,  but at _more than 99_.  It is the same issue with `fgets()`, `scanf_s()`, `scanf()`.  Better code would use a helper function that to handle reading a _line_ and cope with extra data per code's requirements.

Comment: @YahavB "It tells scanf to not stop reading when thers a white space and only stop when theres a newline. doesnt it?" --> No.  Who or what text (hopefully some specification) suggested `s` is useful here?  The scan specifier is `"%[^\n]"`.  The next part of the _format_ string `"s"` is junk.

Comment: @YahavB it says **the `s`** serves no purpose. The format spec `%[]` isn't a subset of `%s`. They are two independent specifiers with differing behaviour, but you have specified the "beginner's mistake" of `"%[^\n]s"`